# Is there a callback to the Ti.Media.switchCamera(Ti.Media.CAMERA_FRONT)?

Tags: ipad, titanium

I am having an issue with the camera switching in Titanium on iPad, so far, I'm guessing it will be an issue on Android as well. Now this does not happen all the time but perhaps every 10 times i try to take the picture. This is what I get from the iPad console:

```
<Warning>: UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to take picture; camera is changing modes.
```

And here is the code:

```
var takePicture = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width: '260dp',
    height: '80dp',
    backgroundColor: '#62bb47',
    backgroundImage: 'none', 
    top: '520dp',
    borderRadius: 10
});
var takePictureIcon = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: '/images/icons/10_device_access_camera.png',
    left: '10dp'
});
var takePictureLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: Alloy.CFG.customL.strings('take_photo'),
    width: '60%',
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    font: {
        fontSize: '24dp'
    },
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
});
takePicture.add(takePictureIcon);
takePicture.add(takePictureLabel);

takePicture.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.Media.takePicture();
});

takePicture.addEventListener('doubletap', function(e){
    return false;
});

takePicture.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    takePicture.setBackgroundColor('#34aadc');
});

takePicture.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    //Ti.Media.takePicture();
    takePicture.setBackgroundColor('#62bb47');
});

container.add(takePicture);
overlay.add(container);

//  DIRECTORIES AND STORING PICS
// get a handle to the as-yet non-existent directory
var masterPicsDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'masterPics');
masterPicsDir.createDirectory(); // this creates the directory

// get a handle to the as-yet non-existent directory
var transactionPicsDir = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'transactionPics');
transactionPicsDir.createDirectory(); // this creates the directory

$.cameraView.hide();
takePicture.hide();

Titanium.Media.showCamera({

    success:function(event)
    {
        var image = event.media;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(event.media));
        Ti.API.debug('Our type was: '+event.mediaType);
        if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
        {
            //var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({width:$.cameraView.width,height:$.cameraView.height,image:event.media});
            var image = event.media;
            var base64 = Ti.Utils.base64encode(event.media).toString();
            //alert(base64);
            //alert('we should save the picture to gallery and update the employee model with the src of the picture');
            //
            //  IF EMPLOYEE DOES HAVE A MASTER PHOTO FILE NAME
            if(!employee.get('photoFileName') || employee.get('photoFileName').indexOf('MasterPhoto') === 0){

                //alert( 'Make new master' + employee.get('photoFileName') );

                var masterFilePath = transactionType + '_' + employee.get('badge') + '_' + transactionTime + '.png';
                var transactionFilePath = transactionType + '_' + employee.get('badge') + '_' + transactionTime + '.png';

                var masterPicture = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, masterFilePath);
                //masterPicture.write(image);
                masterPicture.write(base64);
                masterPicture.move('masterPics/' + masterFilePath);
                masterPicture = null;

                var employeePicture = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, transactionFilePath);
                //employeePicture.write(image);
                employeePicture.write(base64);
                employeePicture.move('transactionPics/' + transactionFilePath);
                employeePicture  = null;

                //alert(masterFilePath);
                employee.set({photoFileName: 'masterPics/' + masterFilePath});
                employee.save();
                transactionEntry.set({photoFileName: 'transactionPics/' + transactionFilePath});
                transactionEntry.set({photoTime: transactionTime});
                //transactionEntry.set({photoData: base64});

                clockHistoryEntry.set({photoFileName: 'transactionPics/' + transactionFilePath});
                clockHistoryEntry.set({photoTime: transactionTime});
            }
            else{

                //alert( 'We have master!' + employee.get('photoFileName') );

                var transactionFilePath = transactionType + '_' + employee.get('badge') + '_' + transactionTime + '.png';
                var employeePicture = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, transactionFilePath);
                //employeePicture.write(image);
                employeePicture.write(base64);
                employeePicture.move('transactionPics/' + transactionFilePath);
                employeePicture  = null;

                transactionEntry.set({photoFileName: 'transactionPics/' + transactionFilePath});
                transactionEntry.set({photoTime: transactionTime});
                //transactionEntry.set({photoData: base64});

                clockHistoryEntry.set({photoFileName: 'transactionPics/' + transactionFilePath});
                clockHistoryEntry.set({photoTime: transactionTime});
            }

            //alert('about to fire the go to confirmation event');
            $.cameraView.fireEvent('go_to_confirmation', {
                employee: args.data.employee,
                departmentName: departmentName,
                transactionEntry: transactionEntry, 
                clockHistoryEntry: clockHistoryEntry
            });
            //$.cameraView.add(imageView);  
        }
        else
        {
            alert("got the wrong type back = " + event.mediaType);
        }
    },
    cancel:function()
    {
            alert('You canceled the action.');
    },
    error:function(error)
    {
        // create alert
        var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera'});

        // set message
        if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA)
        {
            a.setMessage('Please run this test on device');
            console.log("Firing after error on simulator, badge number to pass: " + args.data.employee);
            $.cameraView.fireEvent('go_to_confirmation', {
                employee: args.data.employee,
                transactionEntry: transactionEntry, 
                clockHistoryEntry: clockHistoryEntry
            });
        }
        else
        {
            a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + /*error.code*/ JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log('Camera error: ' + /*error.code*/ JSON.stringify(error));
            Alloy.CFG.log('Error', 'Camera error: ' + /*error.code*/ JSON.stringify(error));
        }

        // show alert
        a.show();
    },
    overlay : overlay,
    saveToPhotoGallery:false,
    allowEditing:false,
    mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
    showControls : false,
    autohide : true,
    //make the picture inside the camera smaller so that we can than place an overlay around it
    transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({
        scale : 0.5
    })
});

Ti.Media.switchCamera(Ti.Media.CAMERA_FRONT);
//$.cameraView.show();
setTimeout( function(){ takePicture.show(); }, 1500);
```

Comment: What I was able to do is this:

`Ti.Media.switchCamera(Ti.Media.CAMERA_FRONT);
var changeCameraInt = null;
changeCameraInt = setInterval(function(){
 if (Ti.Media.camera === Ti.Media.CAMERA_FRONT) { 
  console.log('Front camera');
  Alloy.Globals.cameraOverlay.takePicture.show();
  clearInterval(changeCameraInt); 
  changeCameraInt = null;
 }else{
  console.log('Back camera');
 }
}, 10);`


But it still sporadically tells me that the camera is in the process of switching even though the var Ti.Media.camera is equal to CAMERA_FRONT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a 1 second timeout after instantiating the camera and right before turning it around from back to front, also added a 500 millisecond timeout before letting the takePicture event go through.